# C: Wrong parameter in called function

Tags: c

General question:

In main I call function dd_draw_string() with parameters as seen below.
The problem is that the parameter length isn't handed over the right way.
So  when I call the function with length = 6 and look up the handed over with breakpoint in called function and now the parameter has the value  length = 4294967296 (0xffff ffff).

It's not the full code, but it should be enough to show my issue.

font.h:

```
/*
 * font.h
 */

#ifndef FONT_H
#define FONT_H

#include "stdint.h"

void dd_draw_string(Color* color, uint32_t x, uint32_t y,  char* c, uint32_t length);

#endif /* FONT_H */
```

Main:

```
#include "font.h"
int main() {

    init();

    while (1)
    {
        Color zero = BLUE;
        char bla[] = "hure";
        uint32_t laenge = 6;
        dd_draw_string(&zero, POSITION_NEXTTO_GRAPH_X, POSITION_CURSORX1_TEXT_Y, bla, laenge); //Cursor X1
     }
}
```

font.c

```
void dd_draw_string(Color* color, uint32_t x, uint32_t y, char* c, uint32_t length)
{

    uint8_t current_index;

    /*
     * switch over handed y position
     */
    switch(y)
    {
    case POSITION_BELOW_GRAPH_Y:
                if(x == POSITION_NEXTTO_GRAPH_X && length == FIELD_TIME_LENGTH)
                {
                    for(current_index = 0; current_index < FIELD_TIME_LENGTH; current_index++)
                    {
                        /*
                         * delete old char at current_index -> write = false
                         */
                        dd_draw_char(color, POSITION_TIME_TEXT_X + current_index * FONT_COLUMNS,
                                     POSITION_TIME_TEXT_Y, field_time[current_index], false);
                        /*
                         * update old char to current char in field
                         */
                        field_time[current_index] = c[current_index];
                        /*
                         * draw current char at display
                         */
                        dd_draw_char(color, POSITION_TIME_TEXT_X + current_index * FONT_COLUMNS,
                                     POSITION_TIME_TEXT_Y, field_time[current_index], true);
                        }
                }
                break;
```

By the way, I'm programming with TM4C1294NCPDT, but I think it's a general C issue.

Comment: This will go out of bounds for c if FIELD_TIME_LENGTH > 5.  "hure" + \0 = a 5-character string.

Comment: How is `field_time` declared? Your code reads string `c` at positions up to `length`. You pass 6, but the string you pass has length 4 (or 5, with zero terminator). How is this supposed to work?

Comment: #define FIELD_TIME_LENGTH 6
char field_time[FIELD_TIME_LENGTH]
But i think thats not the point, the problem is before reaching switch case still at first line of function and the handed parameters should be independent of following code, shouldnt?

Comment: @P. Ribback: Should be, yes. But parameters are typically stored in the stack next to local variables. If you damage stack memory by writing of ouf bounds on some local array, you can dectroy the value of a parameter as well.

Comment: @AnT But i have still the same problem if don't write in loop.

Comment: Where are you setting the breakpoint?  The stack might already have been trashed

Comment: The value you are seeing is equivalent to 2^32 and therefore, overflows to 0, so maybe the variable has not been assigned yet.

Comment: If you think this is a general problem, you should also post compiler details and the C flavor you're using.